# asp.net listview in ajax panel not refreshing after databind

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview, updatepanel

I am having a problem updating a listview's databinding when inside a update panel. The listview is to do a databind and return some user names. 
I have tested the databind by triggering it from an asp button and it works fine like so.

```
protected void getFacebookFriends(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<testResult> getFriends = (from i in lqDataContext.test(base.UserId) select i).ToList();
        lvFacebookFriends.DataSource = getFriends;
        lvFacebookFriends.DataBind();

    }
```

when I try do this via ajax using

```
<telerik:RadAjaxPanel ID="updateFriends" runat="server" OnAjaxRequest="updateFriends_AjaxRequest">


 function invokeAjaxRequest() {
        $find("<%= updateFriends.ClientID%>").ajaxRequestWithTarget("<%= updateFriends.UniqueID %>", 97);
    }
```

protected void updateFriends_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
        {
            List getFriends = (from i in lqDataContext.test(base.UserId) select i).ToList();
            lvFacebookFriends.DataSource = getFriends;
            lvFacebookFriends.DataBind();
            updateFriends.EnableAJAX = false;
        }

I can see in debug that I get through  updateFriends_AjaxRequest without error but the ui has not change.

Thanks for helping me understand this.

Mark

Comment: why not just use a regular updatepanel? the postback will be caught and the listview will re-render with the new information asynchronously

Comment: That was it. I was just over thinking the workflow I guess. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap it in a regular update panel. The postback will be caught and the listview will re-render with the new information asynchronously.